# In Android which path is recommend for large storage?

Tags: android

I have a large package, which is about 200MB size, will be download when my app launchs. Which path is recommend for storing it? '/data/data' or '/sdcard/Android/data'?

Comment: Can you give your user the choice?  200MB is a lot to ask from a phone's internal memory.

Comment: what would be the acceptable size for internal storage?

Comment: Did you take a look at this? http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

Comment: I didn't use obb because I have my own resource management which would also be used in my iOS versions.

Answer (score 0):

I think the default choice is SDCARD,`Context.getExternalFilesDir`,which the system will take care of deleting if the application is uninstalled

Comment: I tried that interface but it would throw NPE sometimes randomly which makes me feel this place is not stable

Comment: @jayatubi Check it first. Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState(), or else `getFilesDir()`